# combine two different multidimensional array based on key in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
$arr1 = [
    ["label" => "January", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "February", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "March", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "April", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "May", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "June", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "July", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "August", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "September", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "October", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "November", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "December", "value" => "0"]
];

$arr2 = [
    ["label" => "January", "value" => "20"],
    ["label" => "March", "value" => "30"],
    ["label" => "April", "value" => "24"],
    ["label" => "May", "value" => "10"],
    ["label" => "July", "value" => "0"],
    ["label" => "November", "value" => "34"]
];
```

I want to combine these two arrays values should be replaced in place of "0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wanna see some array function MAGIC?!? ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TjPQ3))

```
var_export(
    array_values(  // remove temporary keys
        array_replace_recursive(  // replace first array values with second
            array_column($arr1,NULL,'label'),  // assign temporary keys using label values
            array_column($arr2,NULL,'label')   // assign temporary keys using label values
        )
    )
);
```

---

Alternatively, you could use this to achieve the same result: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OSmtO))

```
$arr1=array_column($arr1,NULL,'label');  // temporary keys
foreach($arr2 as $row){  // loop only the new values
    $arr1[$row['label']]['value']=$row['value'];  // assign new values
}
var_export(array_values($arr1));  // remove temporary keys and print to screen
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'January',
    'value' => '20',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'February',
    'value' => '0',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'March',
    'value' => '30',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'April',
    'value' => '24',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'May',
    'value' => '10',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'June',
    'value' => '0',
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'July',
    'value' => '0',
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'August',
    'value' => '0',
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'September',
    'value' => '0',
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'October',
    'value' => '0',
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'November',
    'value' => '34',
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'label' => 'December',
    'value' => '0',
  ),
)
```